# Symfony2 using http-basic and preauthentication together

Tags: security, symfony, basic-authentication, api-key

#### What do I need

In my application I have a following schema

```
users (id(PK), username, email(unique), password, etc)
devices (id(PK), device_id, status, user_id)
```

Relation

```
user HAS ONE device
```

The application needs to support basic authentication in two variations.

- **Variation one**: Normal, **email as username and password**. This approach will be used by the admin console. The admin console just like an webapp.
- **Variation two**: email as username, **device id as password**. This approach will be used by mobile application. During the authentication process from device, it will pass the device id as password. Since a user will have only device at a time, the authentication process will match the device id and email to identify the user.

#### What I tried?

I have basically followed [symfony tutorial on api key based authentication](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html) for the second variation and `http-basic` for the first. Please find my security.xml below.

Here, I need the firewall setup to pass when any of the underlying authentication mechanism passes. For instance, in case of web authentication, only http-basic will pass, in case of device login only simple-preauth will pass.

**security.xml**

```
<srv:container xmlns="... ...">

  <config>
    <firewall name="resource" pattern="^/" stateless="true">
        <http-basic realm="Webservice" />
        <simple-preauth authenticator="device_authenticator" />
    </firewall>

    <provider name="administrators">
      <entity class="AppBundle\Entity\User" property="email"/>
    </provider>
    <provider name="device_id_user_provider" id="device_id_user_provider" />

    <encoder class="AppBundle\Entity\User" algorithm="bcrypt" cost="12"/>

  </config>
</srv:container>
```

**services.xml**

```
<container xmlns="... ...">

   <services>
       <service id="device_id_user_provider"
                class="AppBundle\Security\DeviceIdUserProvider">
           <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
       </service>
       <service id="device_authenticator" class="AppBundle\Security\DeviceAuthenticator">
            <argument type="service" id="device_id_user_provider" />
       </service>
   </services>
</container>
```

#### My problem

For every request the firewall tries to pass both of the authentication mechanisms. Hence its always responding with 401.

- Did I set this up in a wrong way?
- Or a firewall MUST pass all of its underlying auth mechanisms?
- Or this is happening only because of using preauthentication?
- Any recommended approach to achieve this?